# Angular table - display hidden element onClick

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a column in a table that has an input field, I only want to show the input when the button is clicked. I was using ng-if to display when clicked, however when the button is clicked, all of the input elements display. I only want the input for a row to display.

HTML

```
    <td *ngIf="!hideStockLevels && row.">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showInput(row)">Add unit</button>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td *ngIf="!hideStockLevels && !this.isButtonVisible" [hidden]="this.isButtonVisible">
     <input (focusout)="updateUnit(row)" class="inputWidth" [(ngModel)]="unitMap[row.id]" type="text"  value="{{row.Unit}}" [disabled]="dateReceived !== null">
     </td>
```

Comment: what is `row.`? and what is `this.isButtonVisible` ?

Comment: Why do use this in html?

Comment: A boolean value - but I'm looking to only show one row when clicked

Comment: Can you put your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngif-click

Comment: That's great, that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: If you put your code there I can help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row needs to have an unique identifier so we know which row to show/hide. You are using just on variable. Add another (boolean) property to each object, which you toggle on click, for example:

```
<td>
   <button (click)="row.hidden = !row.hidden">Add unit</button>
</td>

<td [hidden]="row.hidden">
  <input .... />
</td>
```

I don't know how you toggle when input should be hidden, but then just switch the `hidden` property to `false`, when you want to do that.